# Perl split with regular expression to retrieve values in array

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, split

I have the following file:

```
id001   word1(100);"word2"(100);"word3"(98);"word4"(98);"word5"(94);word6;
id002   word1(100);word7(100);word8(100);word9(100);word10;word11;
```

I want split each lines of my file to retrieve id (=id00x), val (=wordX) and int (=100) in array.
My code :

```
my @fields = split /[\t();"]"?/, $line;
$id = $fields[0];
for ( my $i = 1; $i < @fields; $i +=2 )
{
  $val=$fields[$i];
  $int=$fields[$i+1]
}
```

I retrieve just id and val that are not between double quote.Please can you give me few leads?

Comment: `$fields[i]` will refer to `$fields[0]`, and unless you are using `use warnings` it won't tell you why.

Comment: yes i forgot the dollars!!

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to your script and fix whatever errors and warnings appear. Use `use Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper \@fields` to see what the output of your split really is.

Comment: i do that and i print my @fields but i obtain just the values which are not between double quote. I think it's my regex is no good but i verify with regex tool tester and it split the good arguments : " () ; \t.

Comment: Could you post an example of file: I really don't understand why the first line has `""` while others don't.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post some of the actual data that you want to split? I'm assuming that the data is not actually the words "val" and "int" repeated over and over. If you can't post the actual data, it'd help if you did a little more creative obfuscation, instead of reusing the same string over and over.

Comment: id001   word1(100);"word2"(100);"word3"(98);"word4"(98);"word5"(94);word6;
id002   word1(100);word7(100);word8(100);word9(100);word10;word11;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here **is** the regexp. You can verify this by putting in a loop immediately after doing the split, like this:

```
  my @fields = split /[\t();"]"?/, $line;
  $id = $fields[0];
  foreach my $field(@fields) {
    print("field is $field\n");
  }
```

That will show you that you have several empty fields, and that's why you don't get anything into your variables. The reason for the empty fields is that the regexp will allow any one of the listed characters to act as a word boundary, so when you have more than one of them in succession, they will cause several consecutive splits.

I'd make it easier by not trying to split the entire line at once, Instead I'd start by splitting the line into smaller parts, and then use a regexp to extract the parts. Here's my suggestion:

```
my @fields = split /[\t;]/, $line;
$id = $fields[0];
for ( my $i = 1; $i < $#fields; $i++ )
  {
    ($val, $int) = $fields[$i] =~ /\"?(\w+)\"?\((\d+)\)/;
    print("val is $val, int is $int\n");
  }
```

Also note that the way to get the number of objects in an array is `$#arrayname`, not `@arrayname`. The latter also works in a scalar context, but it's a bad habit to get into.

---

**Below here is the original answer, which was just about syntax**

Here's at least one error:

```
$val=$fields[i];
$int=$fields[i+1]
```

You need to use `$` before the `i` as well, like so:

```
$val=$fields[$i];
$int=$fields[$i+1]
```

Comment: I've been programming perl for almost 20 years now. I still miss stuff like that sometimes...  and it's always easier to find the errors in someone else's code than in your own.

Comment: Now I've added an actual solution, I hope I understood your question correctly this time!

Comment: it's perfect but i have a problem when my words have not values like that (int)!

Comment: What do you want to happen when the word doesn't have a value? Do you want to store it with a value of 0, or do you want it to not be stored, at all?

Comment: my final goal is to stock in two hash, one which contain %hash{$id}=val and the other which contain %hash{$id}=int. So i would have all val into "%hash{$id}=val" even if there is not int and into %hash{$id}=int just all the int.

Comment: i use the warnings in my code and i have this alert "Use of uninitialized value $val in say at .". This is due to no presence of value for some words, i think. So i tried to modify the regex but unsuccessful.

Comment: i change the regex by that : `my ($val, $int) = $fields[$i] =~ /\"?(\w+)\"?\(*(\d+)*\)*/;`. it works for the "wordX" but I am not sure it is very nice.

Comment: it works for the words that haven't values `my ($val, $int) = $fields[$i] =~ /\"?(\w+)\"?\(*(\d*)\)*/;`